# Постановка знака препинания при использовании фразы «я сказал(-а)»

Tags: пунктуация, тире, глаголы, диалог

Хочу узнать, какой знак препинания должен стоять между словами в подобных предложениях:

*1. «Я сказала (?) замолчи»;
2. «Я сказал (?) спокойно»;
3. «Я сказал (?) бегом» и т. д.*

В диалоге нужно оформлять это как прямую речь или, может, ставить запятую или тире?

Comment: "В диалоге нужно оформлять это как прямую речь" - О ЧЕМ ЭТО? Диалог — это разговор двух или более лиц, чьи слова передаются без изменений. Он состоит из последовательных реплик. Это вопросы, ответы, замечания одного собеседника в ответ на слова другого. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=155#pp155    http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=160#pp160

Comment: Вообще говоря, вопрос надо было сразу отправить на доработку ввиду неясности.  «Я сказала (?) замолчи». К чему здесь кавычки?  Что это за дословное высказывание?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно любой знак - нейтральную запятую или более "гнетущие" двоеточие или тире.

Но не как прямую речь оформлять.

1. «Я сказала, замолчи»; «Я сказала: замолчи!»; «Я сказала — замолчи!»
2. «Я сказал, спокойно»; «Я сказал: спокойно!»; «Я сказал — спокойно!»
3. «Я сказал, бегом»; «Я сказал: бегом!»; «Я сказал — бегом!»

---

В [аналитической статье](https://29.ru/text/health/2020/10/27/69517727/#card_1) про «токсичные» для детского уха реплики приведены такие примеры:

«Закрой рот, я сказала»;  «Рот свой закрой, кому сказала», —

то есть обходятся спокойной запятой.

---

Но если вопрос всё-таки о диалоге (а не монологе, как я восприняла приведённые реплики), то двоеточие и кавычки.

Я сказала: "Замолчи!" — "Сама замолчи!" и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

**Варианты оформления дословного высказывания**

Содержание высказывания с указанием  автора  может оформляться в виде **прямой речи**,  но существуют и другие варианты.
В некоторых случаях выбор является **авторским,** но чаще он определяется **содержанием, структурой и интонацией** предложения, а также необходимостью отделить прямую речь от авторских слов. (Наибольшую выделительную способность имеет прямая речь в обычном виде.)  Один из способов  оформления — это бессоюзное сложное предложение **(БСП)** со значением изъяснения.

**Три возможных варианта** оформления БСП при **изъяснительных** отношениях: (1) Я сказала: **замолчи**. (2) Я сказала — **замолчи**. (3) Я сказала, **замолчи.**

1. [По правилам](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150#pp150) **двоеточие** считается основным знаком, но **тире** часто заменяет двоеточие. Про возможность **запятой** также говорится у Розенталя: **Примечание** (к пункту 6). При отсутствии предупредительной интонации двоеточие в этих случаях не ставится: *Сейчас не поедешь, жарко* (Ч.).
2. Для **разговорной речи** подходят два варианта (двоеточие обозначает подчеркнутую паузу, что нехарактерно для  разговорного стиля): (1) *Я сказала — **замолчи**.* (2) *Я сказала, **замолчи**.*

Эти варианты также различаются **по величине паузы**. Самым подходящим знаком является **запятая**, что соответствует спокойной **интонации**. Увеличенная пауза при тире — это уже разговор на повышенных тонах, тогда в конце предложения желательно поставить **восклицательный** знак.

3. А как  же **семантика?** Предложение по своей грамматике и структуре явно выражает **недовольство** ситуацией. Но это можно обозначить и спокойным тоном, собеседник поймет настроение говорящего.
4. В конечном счете выбор определяется **по ситуации.**

**Ситуация "Не поняли друг друга"**

— *Я тебе объясняю еще раз...*

— *Я сказала, **замолчи**. Не нужно объяснять.*

— *Почему я должен все время молчать?*

— *Я сказала — **замолчи!***

Comment: Кочующий вопрос  https://ask.profi.ru/q/znaki-prepinaniya-pri-ispolzovanii-frazy-135179/